# gradle - How to define different library versions for all flavors?

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle

In our project we made important changes in one of the libraries. But our PM wants to keep original lib version AND changed lib. So they want to distribute both of these versions for all our clients. (may sound odd, probably)

My task is to specify these lib versions in gradle. So that we would be able to make builds for all "kinds" of our clients. Without changes in the code or build.gradle.

Suppose, my flavors look like that:

```
productFlavors {
    firstClient {
     ...... 
    }
    secondClient {
     ...... 
    }
    thirdClient {
     ......
    }
  }
```

and buildTypes:

```
buildTypes: {
    debug {
     ...... 
    }
    staging {
     ...... 
    }
    release {
     ......
    }
  }
```

**Question** >> Is it possible to define/specify another "dimension"/"parameter" along with flavors and buildTypes?

In my case it's lib versions. I hope there's some way of doing that (I don't really want to define this by duplicating flavors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For those who will come across this question.*

**(1)**

First, we need to define flavor dimensions - in my case that are flavors and lib versions:

```
flavorDimensions "flavor", "lib_version"
```

Second, for existing flavors define dimension "flavor"

```
productFlavors {
    firstClient {
        dimension "flavor"
        ...... 
    }
    
    // ... other flavors
    // ...
}
```

Third, for different lib versions define different dimensions for libs.

```
productFlavors {
    // ...
    // ... other flavors

    oldLib {
        dimension "lib_version"
    }
    
    newLib {
        dimension "lib_version"
    }
}
```

So, for my case result would look like this:

```
flavorDimensions "flavor", "lib_version"

productFlavors {
    firstClient {
        dimension "flavor"
        ...... 
    }
    
    secondClient {
        dimension "flavor"
        ...... 
    }

    thirdClient {
        dimension "flavor"
        ...... 
    }

    oldLib {
        dimension "lib_version"
    }
    
    newLib {
        dimension "lib_version"
    }
}
```

Now we can choose Build Variant according to our needs.

**(2)**
Don't forget about different lib versions for different dimensions! In dependencies section define these lib versions:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    // ... other dependencies

    oldLibImplementation ('org.example:libexample:1.0_old')
    newLibImplementation ('org.example:libexample:1.0_new')
}
```

**NOTE**

In my case though there was a huge difficulty. For one of the libs I should've set `transitive = false` for one of the libs:

```
    implementation(project(':lib-example')) {
        transitive = false
    }
```

But which one? You have to find in yourself in your project.